# Dealing with unknown option '--variant' when setting up a block environment

Tags: block-editor

I'm on windows 10 with npm version 8.1.1, and node version 16.13.0

Within Visual Studio Code, I am in my plugins directory at the terminal.

From the terminal when I type in `npx @wordpress/create-block --variant dynamic learn01-dyn-block`
and press enter, it first asks me...

```
Need to install the following packages:
  @wordpress/create-block
  Ok to proceed? (y)
```

and I press y on my keyboard to proceed.  But then it says...

`error: unknown option '--variant'`

why is that?
I'm attempting to follow the example in the [docs here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-create-block/#variant).

Oddly when process the following into the terminal - `npx @wordpress/create-block --help` it displays my options, but no --variant.

```
Options:
  -V, --version                output the version number
  -t, --template <name>        project template type name; allowed values: "static", "es5", the name of an external npm package, or the path to a local directory (default: "static")
  --namespace <value>          internal namespace for the block name
  --title <value>              display title for the block and the WordPress plugin
  --short-description <value>  short description for the block and the WordPress plugin
  --category <name>            category name for the block
  --wp-scripts                 enable integration with `@wordpress/scripts` package
  --no-wp-scripts              disable integration with `@wordpress/scripts` package
  --wp-env                     enable integration with `@wordpress/env` package
  -h, --help                   display help for command
```

1. Is the docs outdated?
2. How can I insure that I am building a dynamic block as opposed to a static block?

Comment: Try deleting the npx cache with `rm -r ~/.npm/_npx/` and then rerun the command. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From the docs https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-create-block/ I would say you have to provide template also for that option, though I never used it.
2. I recommend you to get yourself more familiar with block development, it is very clear if block is dynamic or static, if it has php callback for rendering instead of save procedure in javascript, it is dynamic. Static blocks are recommended, while dynamic blocks are used where static HTML is not sufficient (i.e. dynamically provide data from database). Even then, it is recommended for the sake of better UI to use React - based block in edit function instead of `<ServerSideRender>`, which is slow. In reality, many developers choose to develop dynamic blocks because of insufficient knowledge or React and WordPress block development SDK. Famous ACF blocks plugin is based on the same principle.

Comment: I appreciate your perspective on this. If I'm going to get a taste of react based blocks in edit function, what should I read next?

Comment: I recommend learning basics of React and JSX (being the most popular library there is a ton of courses and you can learn basics also from their page). You'll also need a basics of Redux. As for block development, look at block editor handbook, and there are also a lot of courses, but I cannot recommend any, since I learned from documentation (which is not the best and quickest way I believe)